# How to download a file on a ASP.Net page given a stream from a wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, web

I have a asp.net wep page where I make a POST call to a WCF REST service and it returns a stream of the file.

server code:

```
public Stream GetDocument() {           
    String headerInfo = "attachment; filename=" + FileName;
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = headerInfo;
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

    return new MemoryStream(rawDoc.ByteArray);
}
```

client code:

```
sendPost(Dictionary<string, string> msgDump)
{
    var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgDump);
    var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonContent);
    var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
    byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:63301/DocumentService.svc/GetDocument", byteContent);
    var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
}
```

I get the filestream but at this point I don't know how to get the browser to download the file for you. I am going to be hosting this on IIS so I don't want to do any sort of file.create to a specific path. After a lot of googling I cant come up with a solution. the code may seem off since I didn't copy all of it, but you should get the gist.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you don't want to use a specific path u can just create the file with [Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx).